# Python code loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to make a random number guessing game. I am using:

```
def Guess():
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 100)

    found = False

    while not found:
        _guess = raw_input("Your Guess: ")
        if _guess == randomNumber:
            print "Correct!"
            found = True
        elif _guess > randomNumber:
            print "Too High"       
        else:
            print "Too Low"
```

The problem is that no matter what, it prints "Too High".
I have tried to search online for the problem, but I do not know what to search for.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this??

Comment: string and integer comparisons always return the integer being smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `raw_input()` gives you a *string,* not an integer and, since `"42"` is not actually equal to `42`, it will never be correct<sup>(a)</sup>

You need to turn that string into an integer before you compare, with something like:

```
_guess = int(raw_input("Your Guess: "))
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Note that Python 3 disallows ordered inequality checking for mixed string/numeric arguments, so:

```
"2" > 1
```

will actually raise an error. It still allows direct inequality `!=` and equality `==` checks but still considers string and numerics to be unequal.